# file with quotes in any of the fields to be retained as is in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying so many options but not able to retain the quotes present in the input file onto my output file.

Reproducible code:

```
# Input file
csv_data = '''A,B,C,D,E
234,mno,C22,U,
567,pqr,"C3""",U,5555
999,abc,"C99",D,9999
'''

# Load CSV data into dataframes
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False, engine='python', sep=',')

df.to_csv('output.txt', sep=',', index=False, header=True)
```

Now, the output.txt looks like:

```
A,B,C,D,E
234,mno,C22,U,
567,pqr,"C3""",U,5555
999,abc,C99,D,9999
```

Expected output:

```
A,B,C,D,E
234,mno,C22,U,
567,pqr,"C3""",U,5555
999,abc,"C99",D,9999
```

I just don't want to lose anything present in my input data while saving (including the quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `quoting` to `pd.read_csv` and to `df.to_csv` with `3` (`QUOTE_NONE`):

```
# Load CSV data into dataframes
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), 
                 header=0, 
                 dtype=str,
                 keep_default_na=False, 
                 engine='python', 
                 sep=',', 
                 quoting=3)
print (df)
     A    B       C  D     E
0  234  mno     C22  U      
1  567  pqr  "C3"""  U  5555
2  999  abc   "C99"  D  9999

print (df.to_csv(sep=',', index=False, header=True, quoting=3))
A,B,C,D,E
234,mno,C22,U,
567,pqr,"C3""",U,5555
999,abc,"C99",D,9999
```

---

```
df.to_csv('output.txt', sep=',', index=False, header=True, quoting=3)
```

Comment: this doesn't work if the data within a column contains the delimiter(,) rather its treated as a different column, how to overcome that? generally the column data would be quoted in such cases. i.e., "C99,C1". and I would likewise want to retain the quote and not to treat it as a separate column.

Comment: @SpaceyBot - Hard question if possible in pandas, the best is create new question.

Comment: added as a separate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78151955/delimiter-within-column-data-to-be-ignored-in-pandas