# delimiter within column data to be ignored in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input csv file which shouldn't get modified automatically by pandas to any extent except the fields we modify with dataframe object. say, we use comma (,) as a separator. Now, it may contain:

- data without quotes:

  - plah
  - blah
- quotes in any order and in any number of times. i.e.,

  - "plah"
  - ""plah
  - """plah"
  - ""pl""ah""
- separator within single column data (but they would be quoted left and right most for sure). i.e.,

  - "plah,blah"
  - ""plah"",""blah"

Now in all these cases, pandas shouldn't lose the quotes nor should it treat comma (,) within a single quoted column data as a separate column.

Reproducible code:

```py
# Input file
csv_data = '''A,B,C,D,E
234,mno,C22,U,
567,pqr,"C3""",U,5555
999,abc,"C99",D,9999
678,bns,"C6,C7",F,6666
789,bcd,""""C77,T,7777
'''

# Load CSV data into dataframes
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), header=0, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False, engine='python', sep=',', quoting=3)

df.to_csv('output.txt', sep=',', index=False, header=True, quoting=3)
```

I get the error:

```
ParserError: Expected 5 fields in line 5, saw 6
```

Expectation:

```
A,B,C,D,E
234,mno,C22,U,
567,pqr,"C3""",U,5555
999,abc,"C99",D,9999
678,bns,"C6,C7",F,6666
789,bcd,""""C77,T,7777
```

Answer (score 2):

You disabled quoting (`quoting=3`/`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`), but the fourth line of data

```
678,bns,"C6,C7",F,6666
```

Is most likely supposed to have a quoted field `"C6,C7"`.

Thus you read it as:

```
678   bns   "C6   C7"   F   6666
```

You can't use the quotes as delimiters and keep them in the imported data.

The main issue is that your CSV is invalid. You should either use quotes as quoting characters, or normal characters, they can't be both.

A workaround, that would work if you only have this double use of quotes in a single field, could be to read the file twice in two modes, then to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) based on all columns but `C`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), header=0, dtype=str,
                  keep_default_na=False, engine='python', sep=',',
                  quoting=3, on_bad_lines='skip')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), header=0, dtype=str,
                  keep_default_na=False, engine='python', sep=',',
                  quoting=0, on_bad_lines='skip')

out = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
         .drop_duplicates(['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ignore_index=True)
      )
```

*Note that this won't maintain the original order of the rows.*

Output:

```
     A    B        C  D     E
0  234  mno      C22  U      
1  567  pqr   "C3"""  U  5555
2  999  abc    "C99"  D  9999
3  789  bcd  """"C77  T  7777
4  678  bns    C6,C7  F  6666
```

Comment: I can make changes to my read_csv(..) or to_csv(..) calls as long as it will get me the desired result..

Comment: @SpaceyBot the issue is that your CSV is not valid CSV. `read_csv` won't be able to import it as is. Why do you want to keep the quotes?